# Creating logic for method that returns center value between certain range

Tags: java, c#, math, logic

I need a method that works the following way: If I insert any value between -10 and 10 (like -3, 5 or even 0) it returns 0 if I insert a number between 10 and 30 it will return 20. The intervals are always 20 and should work for any number negative, or positive.

TeddHope hint:

```
 public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

   System.out.println(returnOfMidle(3));     //returns 0 ok
   System.out.println(returnOfMidle(29));    // returns 1, must be 20
   System.out.println(returnOfMidle(-19));  //  returns 0, must be -10 

}
public static int returnOfMidle(int number){
    return (number+10)/20;
}
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Because SO is not a service that generating code. It helps with **programming issues**

Comment: @Kaj It's a question of logic, so I did nothing as I can't visualize a solution.

Comment: @Rotem You answered nothing.

Comment: You have to try something and show it I'm afraid. Them's the rules here.

Comment: No special logic here. It's about receiving the number and check the range to decide what to do @JamseB

Comment: @Kaj is more logic than programming, but I will not post in mathematics community..

Comment: @Kaj Sorry man, I will not use while forever to see what fits better, I wanna a more intelligent solution.

Comment: Here's a hint: add 10, then divide by 20, then look at the integer part. But please, SO is not the place for this kind of broad question. Broadly speaking, it's for getting help fixing software that isn't working properly. Read through the help center.

Comment: I'll repeat, it's all about receiving a number and check the range. Even math has nothing to do here @ JamseB

Comment: @Kaj Ted gave the answer, it's better than talking nonsense.

Comment: What people have been telling you isn't nonsense. They're just telling you how SO works. You have to show us what you've tried.

Comment: @TedHopp I am bulding software, it's not for mathematics.

Comment: @JamseB while? Really ?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the question. An example of a failed try would be nice, but it's not off topic.

Comment: Sorry, @TedHopp your hint does not work as seem in topic code (edited), see how it's useless to post something that.

Comment: @JamesB Why should `-19` return `-10` in your example? By your description it should return `-20`.

Comment: @JamesB Read your own question: "If I insert any value between -10 and 10 (like -3, 5 or even 0) it returns 0"

Comment: That was supposed to be a hint, not a solution. It won't work as is for negative numbers and needs to be scaled by 20 (as in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to fit the bill

```
int CenterValue(int value)
{
    int sign = value > 0 : 1 : -1;
    return (Math.Abs(value) + 9) / 20 * 20 * sign;
}
```

Even simpler:

```
(int)Math.Round(value / 20.0) * 20
```

Comment: It's working for positives, but when I insert -19, for example, it is printing -20 not -10.

Comment: By your logic in the question it should return -20. What is the range that should return -10? If -10 to 10 returns 0 and 11 to 30 returns 20 then it's reasonable that -11 to -30 should return -20.

Comment: You are right, sorry.